# What is best approach to share a utility class between multiple microservices?

Tags: java, microservices, utility

Let's consider I have 5+ different services running and I have one utility class that does some common functionality like string to upper-case or Date related operation.

All services will use this utility class.

***Now one approach is to have utility class in all the services which will be code duplication***

***or create another service for the utility class.***

What will be the good approach or is there any other approach to solve this problem?

Comment: "create another service", no, create a library

Answer (score 5):

For utilities, you should create a shared library instead of another service.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it multiple ways, I will list down some best practices:

### Create a library and adopt in other Microservices

Pros:

- Central place to do all the changes.
- Saving extra Network calls

Cons:

- Library Adoption

Recommendation: Use when your library doesn't make any network call. Using caching / DB mechanisms will be hard in the library.

### Create another Microservice with Unified interfaces

Pros:

- a. Open to caching/DB/customization.

Cons:

- Network calls.

Comment: Why is 'code duplication' a disadvantage of a shared library? "Use when your library doesn't make any network call": I totally disagree.

Comment: Yes!! I agree. I corrected. However, I don't know we consider code duplication only when we are writing it manually only.

Comment: Correct. Wrt code duplication, consider comparing the adoption of a shared library to code generation (i.e. project templates) rather than microservices. Microservices can be used for sharing code but more so for features (that can go offline) rather than shared code functions that must be available 24/7 (due to the network overhead they impose).